# Best Stack Exchange site for asking about Amazon AWS

Tags: support, site-recommendation, amazon

I have several questions about setting up [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) (Virtual Private Cloud/VPC, Load Balancers/ELB) -- I see a lot of questions relating to AWS on Stack Overflow, but my questions aren't really programming question, more specific questions about how to set up Amazon.

Which Stack Exchange site should I use?

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: If there is a StackExchange for ExpressionEngine, and Salesforce Cloud, I would hope that the admins would be beelining for an AWS one as we speak.  In the meantime its all about context of the question (good answers below)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you're setting it up for personal use, then [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If it's for setting up your business infrastructure, then [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). If it's about programming with the AWS SDKs then [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be fine. But Stack Overflow questions about virtualization should be directly related to programming. See my question here about a similar topic: *[Stack Overflow questions about virtualization tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139177/so-questions-about-virtualization-tools)*

Comment: Yep; depends what you're trying to do with it, not necessarily just the product/service. From the question it sounds more like enterprise ouse

Comment: thanks all.  Yes, this is for business, so off to ServerFault!

Comment: Is this answer still accurate as of 2018?

Comment: @EricSeastrand no, now additionally if it involves RDS or Aurura you go to [dba.se]. If it involves the web interface you go to [webapps.se]. And if it's lifecycle/pipeline oriented you can head over to [devops.se]. If you're asking about Amazon Linux or an operating system you can ask on [unix.se], and specifically if you're running a cloud image of Ubuntu, we would politely ask you take your question to [ubuntu.se] (we try to keep all the Ubuntu users in one place, far far away).

Comment: I feel like the segregation of stack exchange is showing its age. A funny analogue for old school tech "silos" inside of a business - devs and sysadmins not talking to each other. My primary role/expertise covers at least 5 different stack exchange sites, and the lines between them are increasingly blurry

Comment: This answer is probably outdated... feel free to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 17):

I've started an [AWS Q&A site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/aws?referrer=2SIKhDc2ZvUN5QfMOt5KEg2) at Area 51; any help with the definition phase would be warmly welcome.

Comment: Followed the Proposal to support the cause, also posted an example question. Hope it moves to next phase soon. I had a question on this silly but less-known fact about [charges for not releasing an unused elastic IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834254/aws-unused-elastic-ip-charges)

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Great to have you on board.

Comment: I support to open the site specific for AWS too

Comment: The status today is `29 more questions with a score of 10`; how can I add more question @AdamMatan

Comment: It's dead, Jim. :(

Comment: I always realized its need.

Comment: Area 51 says: This proposal has been deleted.

Comment: What about a Stack Exchange Q&A for serverless cloud computing (AWS, Google Cloud, Azure, etc.). I happen to have some questions in the field and I think it might make it to a beta, if it's not limited to AWS, or is there a good website for cloud computing, now?

Comment: It is needed for sure it seems like Stack Overflow will be overrun by crappy AWS questinos (I am guilty), or maybe a good splinter site could exist for cloud computing questions.