# Should cloud questions be closed as off-topic (Azure, Amazon EC2, etc.) belonging on Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There are quite a few questions on Stack Overflow that relate to [the cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing). For the purpose of demonstrating my point I'll pick on [Azure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform).

The thing is, it's an infrastructure and the majority of the questions are infrastructure questions, not programming related.

At present there are [7801](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) Azure questions, and even looking down that list [we](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111107/access-rules-for-smtp-services-from-azure-to-corporate-network) [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110640/how-does-content-get-propagated-within-multi-instance-azure-websites) [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109930/sql-azure-failed-connections-but-no-problems) [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109200/signing-urls-in-windows-azure-media-services) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097862/nservicebus-on-azure-which-transport-binding-to-use) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090511/mongodb-on-azure-vm-or-worker-role) that would be ideal candidates to move to Server Fault.

I'm even [guilty of this myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085986/azure-appcmd-startup-task-setting-preloadenabled-for-all-sites) (that's what prompted the question, there never seems to be much attention received on Azure questions).

Should they be closed and possibly migrated to Server Fault?

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139177/so-questions-about-virtualization-tools and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stackexchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws/141944#141944

Comment: @smcg The first link is not relevant, as cloud services are not as much about virtualization as it is about providing reliable capacity.  Whether or not that capacity is provided through virtualization is an implementation detail.